# How to implement MultiSelect dropdown list in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am working on a web page where I need to create and fill a multiselect dropdown for states based on selected country.

I am using this [plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js).

**Html :-**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model._CountryList, new { @class = "form-control countries", @tabindex = "12", @id = "ddlCorrCountry" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateIds, Model._StateList, new { @class = "form-control ms-parent multiselectmulticolumnddlstate nopadd states", @tabindex = "13", @id = "ddlCorrState" })
```

**jQuery (Update):-**

```
  function makeMultiSelect() {
        $('select.multiselectmulticolumnddlstate').multipleSelect({
            multipleWidth: 190,
            width: '100%',
            filter: true,
            multiple: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            animate: 'none', // 'none', 'fade', 'slide'
            placeholder: '-- Select --',                
            selectAllText: 'Select All',
            allSelected: 'All Selected',
            countSelected: '# of % selected',
            noMatchesFound: 'No matches found',
            onClick: function () {                    
            },
            onOptgroupClick: function () {                   
            },
            onUncheckAll: function () {                   
            },
            onClose: function () {                   
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        makeMultiSelect();
        $('body').on('change', '#ddlCorrCountry', function () {
            GetAllStates();
        });

        function GetAllStates() {
            try {
                $('#ddlCorrState').empty();
                var params = { "SId": $('#ddlCorrCountry').val(), "All": false }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/utility/getstates",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $.each(data, function () {
                            $('#ddlCorrState').append("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>");
                        });
                        makeMultiSelect();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText + ' Error:' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (ex)
            { alert('EX:' + ex.message); }
        }
    });
```

On page load I am getting below first image which is correct, but while changing/selecting any country its totally distorts as shown in image 2 and even state dropdown is not opening by clicking on it.

**Note** here I am calling a partial view in modal popup, TIA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a start it needs to be `ListBoxFor()` not `DropDownListFor()` if you want a multiple select (and the `StateIds` property needs to be `IEnumerable<T>` if its not already)

Comment: "country its totally distorts as shown in image 2" you might forgot to reference plugin css file.

Comment: I am using it as  public Nullable<Int32> StateIds { get; set; }

Comment: css is there thats why in 1st image its not distorted..

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to an `int?` property - it needs to be `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: I have implemented it on another page in the same way, only difference is there I did not require to fill it on change of any other selector..

Comment: Please update country on change code here

Comment: sorry @Stephen its public string[] StateIds{ get; set; }

Comment: Did you also change it to `ListBoxFor()`? But you have not shown the code relating to how the 2nd ones options are being updated based on changing the first

Comment: I have updated the code , let me check it with ListBoxfor..

Comment: I am not familiar with that plugin (and you have just shown a link to the js code which is of no help - you should link to the actual site). But your initializing the plugin multiple time - on first load, and then again when you select an option in the first one. That would be wrong (unless you destroyed previous instances). Like most similar plugins, I assume there will be a method your can call to just update the options.

Comment: I have just changed it to call twice, I thought it might be required as its distorted on ajax call..

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Try $('select.multiselectmulticolumnddlstate').multipleSelect("refresh") inside $.each after append.

Comment: Your calling `makeMultiSelect` in `document.ready()` and then again **each** time an option in selected in the first dropdown. It should only be initialized once (and you just refresh/update it each time an option is selected) Without knowing what plugin your using I cannot find the documentation for it

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I think this one http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select

Comment: @AjinderSingh, I'm sure your right, but I can even get that site to open :(

Comment: not able to open the site..

Comment: thanks guys it working now..

Comment: @SunilChaudhary - Please post answer as well.

Comment: problem was with the property which was declared wrong int? I changed it to string[]  after @stephens comment..it was by mistake i thought its already string[] but then had a look on it..

Comment: then using the same way its working, I need to call the plugin function again after binding options in each loop of ajax.., thanks @guys...

Comment: It good that it's working but as @StephenMuecke suggested you shouldn't re-initialise plugin every time. Just refresh/update it on each iteration.

Comment: how to refresh it @Singh what is the function?

Comment: @SunilChaudhary - Give it a shot $('select.multiselectmulticolumnddlstate').multipleSelect("r‌​efresh").
Else Please refer to plugin documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159451/discussion-between-ajinder-singh-and-sunil-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just need to call plugin function again after rebinding the dropdown.**

```
 function makeMultiSelect() {
        $('select.multiselectmulticolumnddlstate').multipleSelect({
            multipleWidth: 190,
            width: '100%',
            filter: true,
            multiple: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            animate: 'none', // 'none', 'fade', 'slide'
            placeholder: '-- Select --',
            //addTitle: 'Sunil',
            //delimiter: ', ',
            //minimumCountSelected: 3,
            selectAllText: 'Select All',
            allSelected: 'All Selected',
            countSelected: '# of % selected',
            noMatchesFound: 'No matches found',
            onClick: function () {
                //$("#<%= hdnfld.ClientID %>").val("1");
            },
            onOptgroupClick: function () {
                //$("#<%= hdnfld.ClientID %>").val("1");
            },
            onUncheckAll: function () {
                //$("#<%= hdnfld.ClientID %>").val("1");
                //unSelectAll();
            },
            onClose: function () {
                //var hdnVal = $("#<%= hdnfld.ClientID %>").val();
                //if (hdnVal == "1") {
                //    $('#cover').show();
                //    $(".myhdnBtn").click();
                //}
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        makeMultiSelect();
        $('body').on('change', '#ddlCorrCountry', function () {
            GetAllStates();
        });

        function GetAllStates() {
            debugger;
            $('#ddlCorrState').find('option').remove(); $('#ddlCorrState').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post", url: "/city/getstates", data: { CountryId: $('#ddlCorrCountry').val(), IsAll: true }, datatype: "json", traditional: true, success: function (data)
                {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#ddlCorrState').append('<option value="' + value.Value + '">' + value.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                    makeMultiSelect();
                }
            });
        }
```